Can I ' npm run watch' to get the latest changes from a git repo in to my react application without rebuilding it?
I have a react application where I am going to use json from another git repo.
I want to get the latest changes from that git branch whenever new changes were pushed into it in my local react app by using 'npm run watch' to watch the latest changes.
I used before with two repo with react app one application is child of another application where is used to watch 'npm run watch' to detect my changes from build folder of parent.
Can I use something similar for this changes of JSON file ?
Thanks in advance..

Webhook might need to be configured on the Git Repo, so you'll get notified of the changes to the repo/json file. Upon notification, you will have to update some file (eg: assets/updates.temp <-- timestamp: <push_timestamp>), which is being monitored by the npm-watch.

Hi @DeepakD, thank you for your prompt response. Does this pull the latest changes as well in my react application after which npm watch can trigger?

You have to git pull manually, within the REST endpoint (you manage), configured as part of webhook config.  You get notified (your REST endpoint is invoked) by the GitHub.
